# Background a listening socket server python3

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, sockets, background, daemon

**How can i run a socket server to listen on a specific port while another thread sends HTTP requests at the same time?**

**here is the socket server code**:

```
class ConnectionHandlers:
    def __init__(self, ip=None, port=None, windows=False):
        self.ip = ip
        self.port = port
        self.windows = windows

    def listener(self):
        print("[+] Running listener")
        sock = socket.create_server((self.ip, int(self.port)))
        victim, victim_addr = sock.accept()
        if not self.windows:
            with pwncat.manager.Manager() as manager:
                session = manager.create_session(platform="linux", protocol="socket", client=victim)
                manager.interactive()
        else:
            print("To implement for windows")
```

**here is how the threads are getting called** (From the main code):

```
    def Threads(self):
        # Running the socket server thread
        listener = Thread(target=self.listen(), daemon=True)
        listener.start()
        listener.join()
        # Below thread doesn't start
        bruteforce = Thread(target=self.brute(), daemon=True)
        bruteforce.start()
        bruteforce.join()
```